# Ruby: change time zone issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am trying to change the following in Ruby:
Time.now.utc 
to 
Time.now.pst

However, it is not working. What do you think I am missing?
Thanks!
Mel

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you wrote, and explained better how it is "not working".

Comment: Hi Matt, sure it is the following:start_date => Time.now.utc, 
:end_date => (Time.now.utc + @project.funding_closed_at.to_i.days).utc I need to change UTC to PST but when I do that, it does not seem to make any changes. I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: You need to use either the [TZInfo Ruby Gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/) or the [Rails ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) class.  Your question is not clear enough as it sits.  Please read through those docs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use TimeWithZone:

```
irb(main):005:0> Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
irb(main):006:0> Time.zone.now
=> Mon, 11 Nov 2013 02:23:09 PST -08:00
```

API Reference - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

Comment: Hi Musannif, thanks for this. How does it integrate with my current code which looks as follows? "start_date => Time.now.utc, :end_date => (Time.now.utc + @project.funding_closed_at.to_i.days).utc "

Comment: Actually, it might be simpler to just call `.in_time_zone("Pacitic Time (US & Canada)")` instead of `.utc` on your result